# Zend framework 2 bootstrap is not working in my form

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, zend-framework2

Just now created one form in Zend framework 2. The form is looking like this...

Please open this link to see my ouput image [Bcz I don't have 10 reputation].

http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=bac011a

Now what can I do? How can I bring this form in bootstrap look?

Create.phtml

```
    <?php

    echo '<h1>Create</h1>';
    $form = $this->form;
    $form->prepare();
    $form->setAttribute('action', $this->url('csnuser/default', array('controller' =>               'user', 'action' => 'create')));
    $form->setAttribute('method', 'post');
    echo $this->form()->openTag($form);
    echo $this->formCollection($form);
    echo $this->form()->closeTag();
    ?>
```

Comment: You need to understand what HTML is for. You need to understand what CSS is for. And then you need to understand how to assign CSS classes to `Zend\Form` elements. Nothing of that is a topic which requires a Question on SO as that's basic level understanding. Check the documentation please.

Comment: @sam already bootstrap css classes & js are assigned in layout.phtml.

Answer (score 2):

The following module allows you to do this:

https://github.com/neilime/zf2-twb-bundle - This is for Bootstrap 3.x there are other modules available for lesser versions but assume you are using the latest.

You shouldn't need to alter your code much at all. Probably be something like:

```
    $this->form($form,\TwbBundle\Form\View\Helper\TwbBundleForm::LAYOUT_HORIZONTAL);
```

Some good demos and docs here: http://neilime.github.io/zf2-twb-bundle/2.0/demo.html